# pandas creates 2 copies of files in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, file, group-by

I have a dataframe like as below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import default_rng
rng = default_rng(100)
cdf = pd.DataFrame({'Id':[1,2,3,4,5],
                   'customer': rng.choice(list('ACD'),size=(5)),
                   'region': rng.choice(list('PQRS'),size=(5)),
                   'dumeel': rng.choice(list('QWER'),size=(5)),
                   'dumma': rng.choice((1234),size=(5)),
                   'target': rng.choice([0,1],size=(5))
})
```

I am trying to split the dataframe based on `Customer` and store it in a folder. Not necessary to understand the full code. The issue is in the last line.

```
i = 0
for k, v in df.groupby(['Customer']):
    print(k.split('@')[0])
    LM = k.split('@')[0]
    i = i+1
    unique_cust_names = '_'.join(v['Customer'].astype(str).unique())
    unique_ids = '_'.join(v['Id'].astype(str).unique())
    unique_location = '_'.join(v['dumeel'].astype(str).unique())
    filename = '_'.join([unique_ids, unique_cust_names, unique_location, LM])
    print(filename)
    with pd.ExcelWriter(f"{filename}.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
        v.to_excel(writer,columns=col_list,index=False)
    wb = load_workbook(filename = 'format_sheet.xlsx')
    sheet_from =wb.worksheets[0]
    wb1 = load_workbook(filename = f"{filename}.xlsx")
    sheet_to = wb1.worksheets[0]
    copy_styles(sheet_from, sheet_to)
    #wb.close()
    tab = Table(displayName = "Table1", ref = "A1:" + get_column_letter(wb1.worksheets[0].max_column) + str(wb1.worksheets[0].max_row) )
    style = TableStyleInfo(name="TableStyleMedium2", showFirstColumn=False, showLastColumn=False, showRowStripes=True, showColumnStripes=False)
    tab.tableStyleInfo = style
    wb1.worksheets[0].add_table(tab)
    #wb1.worksheets[0].parent.save(f"{filename}.xlsx")
    wb1.save("test_files/" + f"{filename}.xlsx")  # issue is here
    wb1.close()
print("Total number of customers to be emailed is ", i)
```

Though the code works fine, the issue is in the below line I guess

```
wb1.save("test_files/" + f"{filename}.xlsx")  # issue is here
```

This creates two copies of files.. One in the current folder as jupyter notebook file and other one inside the `test_files` folder.

For ex: I see two files called `test1.xlsx` one in the current folder and one inside the `test_files` folder (path is test_files/test1.xlsx)

How can I avoid this?

I expect my output to generate/save only 1 file for each customer inside the `test_files` folder?

Comment: Probably you need to add prefix `test_files/` to the file name here as well `with pd.ExcelWriter(f"{filename}.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
        v.to_excel(writer,columns=col_list,index=False)`

Comment: Should I do the same during `load_workbook` as well?

Comment: yes :) best is to define the filename as `dir_filename = "test_files/" + f"{filename}.xlsx"` and then use it at every place you are referencing the file

Comment: great. thanks, if you can write as an answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is happening because you are referencing 2 different file names one with the prefix `"test_files/"` and once without it. Best way to handle it will be to define file name as follows

```
dir_filename = "test_files/" + f"{filename}.xlsx"
```

and then reference it in the following places

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(f"{filename}.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    v.to_excel(writer,columns=col_list,index=False)
##
wb1 = load_workbook(filename = f"{filename}.xlsx")
##
wb1.save("test_files/" + f"{filename}.xlsx")
```

Hope it helps

Comment: but you don't reference `dir_filename` anywhere in your code. Is it a typo?